# Traversing a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, traversal

I am trying to traverse each 'node?' of a JSON objet in python. I am trying to implement a recursive function like

```
def function(data):
         for element in data:
                --- do something----
                if (some condition):
                        function(element)
```

what I want to know is how can I find if the element in question is another object or just a string. That is, what should I write instead of 'some condition' in my above code. Like when I travese an XML , I check if it has any children using getchildren() and if it does, I recursively call the function again.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good pythonic way to do it could be something like this :

```
def function(data):
   try:
      for element in data:
         --- do something----
         function(element)
   except TypeError:
      pass
```

Do the stuff and let python raise an exception if you try to iterate on something that is not iterable ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `type` is generally frowned upon in Python in favor of the more-functional `isinstance`.  You can also test multiple types at the same time using `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(myVar, (list, tuple)):
  # Something here.
```

Comment: why? why is frowned upon type?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `type(var)` function to check whether the element is a dictionary or list.

```
def recurse(data):
    for element in data:
        if type(element) is list or type(element) is dict:
            recurse(element)
        else:
            # do something with element
            pass
```